# xcode 10 debugger stops on some breakpoints and don't on some others

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

The breakpoints that are working are defined twice (I don't know how or why they were created twice). When editing those breakpoints the condition item has two radio buttons. The first one is on with the text: "Use parent breakpoint condition, which is not set". The other radio button is near the "classical" text field for the condition. The breakpoints that don't work have only the text field for the condition. I can't find any documentation for this. My questions : What makes I produce one kind of breakpoint and the other one ? Is it a bug ? (Only the working one, with radio buttons should be produced ?). It is not clear for me. What means the text: "Use parent breakpoint condition, which is not set" ? What is a parent breakpoint ? Why are they -when working- produced by pair ? Actually setting a working breakpoint seems to work randomly for me. Does anyone have the same problems ?

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode breakpoint display is mirroring the way lldb treats breakpoints under the covers.

lldb breakpoints come in two parts.

The first part is the "breakpoint specification" - so for instance "line 12 of the file foo.c" or "symbols named foo".  lldb also allows broader search specifications like "any function name matching a regular expression" (`break set -r`) or even "any line of source code matching a given regular expression" (`break set -p`) though Xcode doesn't have UI for these fancier ones.

The root node of the breakpoint in the Xcode display represents the breakpoint specification.

Each specification can resolve to one or more locations in the generated code for your application.  This can happen, for instance, if the breakpoint was on an inlineable function in a header file, which will emit code into each of the compile units that include the header file and use the function.  Or is you set a symbolic breakpoint and that name shows up in more than one shared library.  It can also happen when you set a breakpoint on source lines like

```
for (i = foo(); i < bar(); i += baz()) {
```

since that source line contributes code that gets run in three distinct parts of the evaluation of the for loop.

So the child nodes of each breakpoint listing in Xcode show you the individual locations in the generated code which matched the breakpoint specification.

If a breakpoint has no location nodes, that means lldb couldn't find any places in your code that matched the specification.  You can sometimes see this more clearly if you issue the:

```
(lldb) break list
```

command in the lldb console.

I can't tell why, from your description, some of your breakpoints aren't resolving to locations in your code.  This can happen if you have set a breakpoint in a source file that got built without debug information, for instance.  It can happen if the source location is between some #ifdef's where the condition fails so no code is emitted for those lines.  I'd need more details to know why your particular breakpoints aren't resolving.